# Arrays in Mysql database for image path storing?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

Im building an app where a user can upload multiple images, the path will be stored in the database, but is there a way to put all the paths on a single column (an array type),Im kinda new to mysql and don't know if that exists.

I just want to avoid creating 10 or more columns for each image.

By writing this I realized I should make another table just for images, and link them.

Anyway I would still like to know if there is a way of creating arrays for a column in mysql.

Thank you.

Comment: yep, your conscience is tellin you the right thing, follow your gut. create another table. normalise them

Comment: You could store them as a json and use json_encode and json_decode to write/read

Comment: Tip: Since you're new to MySQL, try searching Stack Overflow for existing answers before posting a new question. Most basic questions are already answered, probably more than once.